# SSRS Multiple rows per page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a number of different addresses made up of multiple fields that I have formatted in a tablix which I will then need to print off to be cut out and attached to envelopes.

I am using report builder 3.0 and am pulling the data by using a pre-built model as the data source that I have no raw SQL access to.

The issue I am having is that instead of having only one column with one address directly under another and therefore having only 8 addresses per A4 page, I want to have 3 columns of addresses per page. Is there an easy way of doing this that i'm missing?

Comment: Try this and come back with any specific issues: http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/create-multi-column-lists-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-2011-10-03/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This is what I wanted. Thank you so much I have managed to solve my issue using this.

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset - assuming it is SQL Based - add a column that calculates which column it should go into and then add a column group to your tablix based on this field:

```
select (row_number() over (partition by AddIDCol order by SortCol)-1) % 3 as ColumnNumber
      ,AddressLine1     -- To get a 0 based list, add the -1 here ^^
      ,AddressLine2
      ,etc
from AddressesTable
```

This works because of the modulo operator `%`, which returns the remainder after doing the given division.  So a zero based row number `%` 3 result table would look like this:

```
RowNum | Mod3
0      | 0        0/3 = 0 remainder 0
1      | 1        1/3 = 0 remainder 1
2      | 2        2/3 = 0 remainder 2
3      | 0        3/3 = 1 remainder 0
4      | 1        4/3 = 1 remainder 1
5      | 2        5/3 = 1 remainder 2
6      | 0        6/3 = 2 remainder 0
7      | 1        7/3 = 0 remainder 1
8      | 2        8/3 = 0 remainder 2
etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately as much as I would like it I have no SQL access to the may be the answer but I am unsure where to use it.

Comment: @mizumi  If you could update your question with how you are pulling your data, you will get more relevant answers.  Context is important.